# Float == Number Assertion error while using sphinx with nodejs

Tags: node.js, sphinx

I am using sphinx for running the following set of queries via nodejs :-

```
sphClient.SetGeoAnchor("latitude", "longitude", lat, long);
sphClient.SetFilterRange("@geodist",0,1000);
var res = sphClient.Query("@country country_name");
```

However when i run this it gives me the following error :-

```
throw new assert.AssertionError({
    ^
AssertionError: "number" == "float"
at SphinxClient.SetGeoAnchor (/node_modules/sphinxapi/lib/sphinxapi.js:395:9)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/posts/egx.js:331:15)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
at Manager.onClientMessage (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at finish (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:288:16)
at Parser.expectHandler (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:299:15)
```

I even understand what the problem is , after viewing sphinxapi.js , i found out that it compares the typeof(lat) , typeof(long) with "float" , however nodejs returns only "number" . I have tried parseFloat . Also changing the comparison to "number" gives me another error like :-

```
/node_modules/sphinxapi/lib/sphinxapi.js:79
        l += Number( obj.hasOwnProperty(k) );
                     ^
ReferenceError: obj is not defined
at len (/node_modules/sphinxapi/lib/sphinxapi.js:79:17)
at SphinxClient.AddQuery (/node_modules/sphinxapi/lib/sphinxapi.js:572:6)
at SphinxClient.Query (/node_modules/sphinxapi/lib/sphinxapi.js:476:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/posts/egx.js:333:25)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
at Manager.onClientMessage (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Comment: When sphinxapi.js was ported from another language, the coder probably forgot to change the asserts to account for JS not having a direct 'float' type. Just change the assert line.

Answer (score 0):

javascript has only one type of numbers which is "double". there are no integers, floats, etc.
no matter what type of number you are testing, you always get "number" as the result:

typeof 1 is "number"

typeof 1.1 is "number"

i don't know what's going on inside sphinx typeof(), but it is normal that everything's a "number".
please post the code or link to where i can find the code. it will help me help you walk through this.

Comment: From what I can see, this https://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi/blob/master/lib/sphinxapi.js appears to be the canonical version of sphinxapi.js. Line 79 is already different, so perhaps the 'obj is not defined' has already been fixed. In fact 395/6 already compere to number not float.

Comment: Ahh! https://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi/commit/3389b3e235e40f995fdef67a7d41397ab5dcb18d AND https://github.com/touv/node-sphinxapi/commit/adf486addaadf6236223fb3bd6db157c59c8481d
So AnuragD you should just download the latest version of sphinxapi.js

Comment: yes i fixed all of the stuff above , i am now comparing it to number , and i also took care of obj . There are no errors now , however i still don't get any results .

Comment: Well "don't get any results" could be just about anything. Thats probably worthy of a new question. Might be something as simple as forgetting to use radians for the coordinates (not degrees!)